# IBOutlet for image button not correctly referencing button after recreating outlet

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, iboutlet

I have a custom button with image. For this I have an IBOutlet to reference it in the viewcontroller.swift file.

The button was working but was hooked up to the wrong outlet. I removed all of the outlets and actions for that button and all similar buttons and then remade them. At that point they stopped working.

I first tried to change the image for the button with this code:

```
star1BackButtonReference.setImage(UIImage(named: "starfull_48dp.png"), forState:
```

This didn't do anything. After thinking the problem was with the code for changing the image i decided to check a few things.

So I tried to hide the button like this:

```
star1BackButtonReference.hidden = true
```

This did not do anything either so I think that there is a problem with the IBOutlet reference star1BackButtonReference and found only the instance where I change/hide the image and the reference.

The reference is like this:

```
@IBOutlet var star1BackButtonReference: UIButton!
```

I checked the referencing outlet on the storyboard and they are correct (One side is viewcontroller other side is star1BackButtonReference).

Answer (score 1):

There must be some mistake you have done in connecting outlet or deleting old one.

If you are deleting referencing outlet then you must remove it's reference also from the `connection inspector`.

So, once delete that outlet for that button and then select that button from storyboard and the click on `connection inspector` and then press `x` for all outlets under the `referencing outlets` in `connection inspector`.

So, finally you have deleted your `IBOutlet` from code and close it's connection also.

Now `ctrl + drag` from your button to your relevant `viewcontroller` opened in assistant editor and popup will appear, make sure that `outlet` is selected beside `connection` and set it's name whatever you want and press `connect`. That's it. now try with this newly connected outlet.

Comment: thank for your response. I tried that but no luck. No errors it just not going invisible or changing images.

Comment: try by setting background and tint color!!!! If it works then there is other problem rather than outlet!

Comment: I don't know how I can do that on an image button. I did alpha though and that has no effect.

Comment: in your `star1BackButtonReference.setImage(UIImage(named: "starfull_48dp.png"), forState: ` this line, why you haven't specified state?